# Global mutable reference object in Play, that get's swapped via Actor

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I want to create a global scope variable that has a **mutable reference**, but use an **immutable object** e.g.

```
var globalMap = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> c)
```

Now I want to be able to use this `globalMap` in all my controllers, how can you do this in play?

I want to create an akka actor that will use a timer, and every x seconds it will create a new map that will be initialized by reading from the db and then become the new reference of the `globalMap` variable.

Note:  I'm not looking for people to say that this is bad design etc., I just want to understand if this is possible and how to go about doing this in play.

Answer (score 2):

Making some value available consistently to a set of readers (threads, controllers, does not matter) requires that you properly publish new values. The first part is to synchronize such that only up to one update runs concurrently, which you solve by using an Actor to do it (there are other ways, but an Actor works). The second part is to synchronize between the writer and the readers such that they only see properly initialized and consistent objects instead of some random garbage. Luckily the JVM has a rather well-defined memory model, so the only thing needed is to mark the variable as `@volatile`.

For an alternative implementation you might want to check prepackaged solutions to this very problem, for example [Akka Agents](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.9/scala/agents.html):

```
import akka.agent.Agent

object MyGlobal {
  val theMap = Agent(Map.empty[String, Int])
}
```

Then your updater (may still be an Actor if you want to conveniently schedule things, but can be any part of the code now) just uses `send` (or `alter` if you need to know when the modification is effective) to update the value while readers use `get` to obtain the current value.

Comment: I wanted to use it after your recommendation but it's deprecated now: `Akka 2.5.13 Deprecation warning` - 
`Agents have been deprecated and are scheduled for removal in the next major version. We have found that their leaky abstraction (they do not work over the network) make them inferior to pure Actors, and in face of the soon inclusion of Akka Typed we see little value in maintaining the current Agents.`

Comment: As long as you stay within one JVM you can use a volatile static field that is only written by one actor that writes immutable object references to it.

Answer (score 0):

Do it the same as without Play.  Put it in an Object `MapHolder`.  Inherit your controllers from a trait with

```
def globalMap = MapHolder.globalMap
```

This is too easy... did you need something more?